# how to handle ASP.NET dbtransaction timeout

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, ado.net, asp.net-2.0, connection-timeout

I have been experiencing db transaction timemouts in an ASP.NET 2.0 & SQL Server 2008 application for several days now.

The issue is something using SQL Server profiler tracing to "a function calling web service".

We have transaction include several stored procedure (sp). But stored procedure #3 has some bytes to save in DB, it consumes time. When the time goes over 25 seconds, it throws a timeout exception message:

> Message : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

My code:

```
using (System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection = o_DB.CreateConnection())
{
     connection.Open();

     System.Data.Common.DbTransaction o_Transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

     try
     {
        - exec sp1
        - exec sp2
        foreach{
            - exec sp3
        }
     }
```

We tried some solutions in the web but it did not work. I hope someone can give a hand to me. **Many Thanks.**

We do not have `timeout` in the connection string in `web.config`, it does not suffer on exception after 15s (default)

We set the transaction timeout in `web.config`:

```
<system.transactions>
    <machineSettings maxTimeout="00:00:30" />
</system.transactions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
using (var ts = CreateTransactionScope(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mySecondsVar)))
{ 
    using (System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection = o_DB.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (IDbTransaction tran = connection.BeginTransaction()) {
        try 
        {
            // your code
        }  
        catch {
            tran.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
    ts.Complete();
}
```

If is "ok", the dispose do the commit automatically.

Answer (score -1):

This you can directly handle by code also.
Please see the below code

```
public DataSet getData(string command)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TESTDB"].ConnectionString;
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(command, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Open();
            adapt.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

The blow line will change the execution time to infinity or until query execution complete.

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

Comment: it is undesirable to set infinite time in production env. can we set transaction timeout other connectionTimeout?

Comment: @johnchan To be clear CommandTimeout and ConnectionTimeout are two different things.   CommandTimeout is the length of time a given command request is allowed to take and is set in code, and ConnectionTimeout is how long the connection handshake is allowed to take and is set in the connection string. Setting either to 0 is indefinite, but they can be set to any number of seconds desired.

Comment: this would set command timeout to infinite, but if the transaction is composed of more than one commands, this would not be the same than setting transaction timeout. 

in general, as said above in the comments, it is not recommended to set timeout to infinite